# Sending json to symfony controller

Tags: php, json, jquery, symfony

I need to pass json data to my Symfony Controller. My ajax function looks like this:

```
var data = '{"firstname":"John"}';
$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: save_url, //path to controller action  
data: {json:data},
success: function(response) {
     // Do something                
}
});
```

In my controller, I try to get my data through:

```
public function createAction(Request $request) {
    $data = $this->getRequest()->get('firstname');          
    return $this->render('MyBundle:Counter:test.html.twig', array(
        'data' => $data          
    ));
```

Just to see if this works, I send `$data` to be echoed in a template. In Firebug I can see the data being sent and everything seems to work, but `$data` is empty and nothing is echoed. Where am I doing this wrong?

EDIT: When I check the response in `Fireburg` console, I see my data there, in place, but it never appears in the template. `var_dump($data)` tells that `$data` is `null`. So, it seems data is being sent but the controller ignores it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be just $request->get('json'); ?

Answer (score 1):

As Marek noticed:

```
$this->getRequest()
```

already returns the request object, you're accessing the `request` property of the request, that doesn't add up. Either try:

```
$data = $this->request->get('json');
```

Or use:

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->get('json');
```

You can, of course assign the return value of `$this->getRequest()` to a variable, and call the `get` method on that var from there on end... anyway, here's my initial answer, it does contain some more tips, and considerations you may find useful:

You *should* be able to get the data this way, though AJAX requests + echoing in a template? That does sound a bit strange. I don't see you passing the `$data` variable to a `$this->render` call anywhere.

This is a copy-paste bit from a controller action in one of my projects. It works just fine there:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    if (!$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {//check if request is AJAX request, if not redirect
        return $this->redirect(
            $this->generateUrl('foo_bar_homepage')//changed this, of course
        );
    }
    $id = $this->getRequest()->get('id',false);//works fine
```

However, I can't begin to grasp why you're doing this:

```
 var data = '{"firstname":"John"}';
```

Why not simply go for:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,//post how you get this URL please...
    data: {firstname: 'John'},//jQ will sort this out for you
    success: function(response)
    {
        console.log(response);
    }
    error: function()
    {
        console.log('an error occured');
        console.log(arguments);//get debugging!
    }
});
```

Then, in your controller you're able to:

```
$this->getRequest()->get('firstname');//it should be John
```

You could even pass `{json:{firstname: 'john'}}` as the data param to `$.ajax`, the only difference in your controller will be, that you have to do this:

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->get('json');
$firstName = $data['firstname'];
```

That *should* work just fine, unless there's somthing you're not telling us :)

*RECAP:*
This is what I'd write:

```
public function createAction()
{//no Request param in controller
    if (!$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {//no ajax request, no play...
        $this->redirect(
            $this->generateUrl('homepage_route')
        );
    }
    $data = $this->getRequest()->get('firstname');
    //return json response:
    return new Response(json_encode(array('dataReceived' => $data));
    //return rendered HTML page:
    return $this->render('MyBundle:Counter:test.html.twig', array(
        'data' => $data          
    ));
}
```

Of course, then the JS code should read:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: 'route/to/create'
    data: {firstname:'John'},
    success: function(response)
    {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

I have tested this, and I see *no reason* why this shouldn't work. It works just fine for me...

Comment: I´ve tried everything in your examples, but the result is still empty. I updated my question.

Comment: @tofu: You're not showing us _how_ you're getting the data. jQ also has well documented default behaviour: `$.ajax` sends the data as x-www-form-urlencoded mime-type, so you needn't decode it. Even if you were to send the data as JSON, I do believe Symfony decodes it for you. Please add the code you're using to decode to your question, so we can verify that

Comment: But the main problem still is the request result is empty. I´m not decoding yet, I only thought that I might need to do that. The first step is to make sure that I CAN send data to my controller.

Comment: @tofu: of course, but if you don't show us _how_ you're trying to get the data into your controller (how you're assigning to `$data`), we can't say for sure there's no mistake being made there, can we? you've just pasted `$data = //get json and decode`, which doesn't show how you're assiging anything to `$data`. I need to see what you're doing there

Comment: I removed that because my original code was wrong. I have updated with one of your suggestions.

Comment: @tofu: But you've not changed the jQ side (at least, not in your answer) `$this->getRequest()->get('firstname');` will only work if you change the `$.ajax` call to `data: {firstname : 'John'};`, with your ajax call the way it is, you'll have to use `$this->getRequest()->get('json');`, and then dump `$data`, It'll probably need some processing before you can parse it...

Comment: {firstname : 'John'}; and $this->getRequest()->get('firstname'); still give me an empty result.

Comment: @tofu: I've added a full working example to my answer (at the bottom), stressing, again, all things you should check. I know the symfony cookbook shows examples where the controller methods expect a `Request` instance as parameter, but honestly, since the controllers should have access to the request (either as a property, or via the `getRequest` method anyway), I'd omit that, if I were you

Comment: I tried your example, and realized $this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest() returns false. Why is that?

Comment: @tofu: That means the controller action is invoked on a regular request. Either the ajax call is triggered by a form submit event (if so, cancel the event by returning false from the jQ event handler, or stop propagation + preventDefault), or, if the ajax request is sent to the same action, wrap your ajax-related code in an `if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()){/*ajax-related code here*/ return new Response(json_encode($data));}` branch

Answer (score 1):

**Please note this was @EliasVanOotegem original example but there are some obvious steps missing**

in the controller i'm reading a few replies as in "I cannot see how this works as i'm getting null" this is because your not correctly keying your object.

i.e.

```
var data = { name : 'john' };

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,//post how you get this URL please...
  data: {json : data},//jQ will sort this out for you
  success: function(response)
  {
      console.log(response);
  }
  error: function()
  {
    console.log('an error occured');
    console.log(arguments);//get debugging!
  }
});
```

as you can now see accessing the requerst object like

```
$request->get('json');
```

refers to the post key for the json data

Answer (score 0):

Is the content what you're trying to retrieve, neither params nor headers.

Try:

```
$request->getContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case `$request->request->get('json')` should do.